# getting the ( was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to get this program to read an argument then to shift the arguments to read again if there are any. If there is not any left to exit, and if initially there are no arguments to exit and change errorlevel to 1. I keep trying to run it and I recieve the "( was unexpected at this time" I believe I have proper formatting. Can anyone give me some clues?

```
if %1 == "" ( 
    echo Usage: %0 varname1 ...
    echo Determines if variable name is defined
    exit /b 1
) 

:again
rem - if %1 is not blank, we loop
if not %1 == "" (
    if not defined %1 echo %1 is NOT defined environment variable.

    if defined %1 echo %1 is defined environment variable.

    rem - shift the arguments and examine %1 again
    shift
    goto again
)
```

Comment: Change both instances of `%1 == ""` to `"%~1"==""`.

Comment: @compo Thank you so much!